# Tabs component with bootstrap

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I want to use the tabs component from bootstrap. My problem is that the tabs are corrects but they don't display the right div.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="tab">Essai</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2" data-toggle="tab">Traitement</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3" data-toggle="tab">Bloc</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4" data-toggle="tab">Parcelle élémentaire </a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-5" data-toggle="tab">Station climatique</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-6" data-toggle="tab">ITK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-7" data-toggle="tab">ITK PRO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-8" data-toggle="tab">Prélèvement</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-9" data-toggle="tab">Analyse</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-10" data-toggle="tab">Mesure plante principale</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-11" data-toggle="tab">Mesure plante CIPAN</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab_content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs-1">
        bonjour1
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-2">
        bonjour2
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-3">
        bonjour3
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-4">
        bonjour4
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-5">
        bonjour5
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-6">
        bonjour6
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-7">
        bonjour7
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-8">
        bonjour8
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-9">
        bonjour9        
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-10">
        bonjour10
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-11">
        bonjour11
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And what I get is the correct tabs but the div `tab-pane` are one above each others. So I can see all my div in the page but I want to see only one div at time.

I follow a tutorial to make it work and I did every things he said but it doesn't work.

Help please !

**EDIT :**

I get this :

[image]

Comment: Is it normal : <ul class="nav nav-tabs">>    ==> Do you see the double '>' ?

Comment: @YenneInfo Thanks I removed it but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: please provide resulting html without php code.

Comment: @miller I updated my post without the php

Comment: replace "tab_content" by "tab-content"

Comment: @YenneInfo It works, thanks :)